# How to create Parties in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm new to Corda and I just developed an app with the help of documentation. The documentation is really awesome, the way they are explaining things. But, I have few questions which I'm not able to find the solution.
To create parties, I have seen in build.gradle file we mention the parties details.

```
node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
```

But, I think this is not the correct way to mention these informations in a file. There must be some Database.

As we can see for each node we are specifying a port and ip. So, it must be an independent process. But, let's say that I have a bank and I have millions of customers then, how we can manage these many processes?

I know my questions are naive but I'm not able to find any solution to my queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Corda 4, the design is for one node per identity (i.e. per `Party` object). Thus each identity requires its own node with its own JVM process and ports.

There has been discussion of how to scale to large numbers of hosted identities (e.g. https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/roadmap_doc_for_project/27242114), but none have been implemented as of yet.

In your use-case (a bank and their customers), it may make sense for only the bank to run a node. The customers would authenticate with the bank and the bank would transact with other nodes on their behalf. This is how online banking works today.